# $G$ be loacally compact abelian group with $G,\hat{G}$ both sigma compact. Let $f\in L^2(G)$ and $\psi_n(x)=\int_{C_n}\hat{f}(\chi)\chi(x)\ d\chi$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

> Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian, $T_2$ group such that $G,\hat{G}$ both are $\sigma$-compact with $G=\bigcup K_n$ and $\hat{G}=\bigcup C_n$ where $K_n,C_n$ are increasing compact subsets of $G$ and $\hat{G}$ respectively. Let $f\in L^2(G)$, define $$\phi_n(\chi)=\int\limits_{K_n} f(x)\chi(x^{-1})\ dx,\hspace{2mm} \psi_n(x)=\int\limits_{C_n}\hat{f}(\chi)\chi(x)\ d\chi$$
> Show that, $\lVert \phi_n-\hat{f}\rVert_{L^2(\hat{G})}\to0$ and $\lVert \psi_n-f\rVert_{L^2(G)}\to0$

I'm able to show the first part. Observe that $\phi_n=(f1_{K_n})\text{^}$, so $\lVert \phi_n-\hat{f}\rVert_2=\lVert(f1_{K_n}-f)\text{^}\rVert_2=\lVert f1_{K_n}-f\rVert_2=\lVert f1_{K_n^c}\rVert_2 $.

Thus, $\lVert \phi_n-\hat{f}\rVert_2^2=\int\limits_{K_n^c}|f(x)|^2\ dx\to 0$ (by DCT)

But I'm unable to argue the second part i.e. $\lVert \psi_n-f\rVert_{L^2(G)}\to0$. Can anyone help me finish the proof? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: So if it is locally compact abelian groups that you are talking about, then you will have the so called [_Pontryagin duality_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality). At that time, you will also have [Fourier inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

For the second proof, it's completely analogous, but use the inverse Fourier transform instead: The inverse Fourier transform of a function g $\in L^1(\widehat{G})$ is defined as $$\check{g} (x) = \int_{\widehat{G}} g(\chi) \chi(x) d\chi$$
So looking back at your problem, you have that $\psi_n$ is just the inverse Fourier transform of $\widehat{f} \ \mathbb{1}_{C_n} $

The Fourier inversion theorem guarantees that $\check{\widehat{f}} = f $ almost everywhere, therefore $||\psi_n - f||_2 = ||\psi_n - \check{\widehat{f}}||_2 = \\ = ||\check{(\widehat{f} \ \mathbb{1}_{C_n})} - \check{\widehat{f}}||_2$

This last term goes to 0 by the exact same reasoning you had used previously.